# Parsing XML file to Nested DICT

Tags: python-3.x, xml, xml-parsing, elementtree

I'm trying to save data from a XML file into a nested dict. In my XML file, shown bellow, I have multiple tags called **DOCUMENT** and nested to it I have a variable number of tags called **LINK**. Then, inside the links I have some URLs inside **ADDRESS** tags

```
<document>
    <description>blah, blah, blah</description>
    <link>
        <description>Document1</description>
        <address>url 1</address>
    </link>
    <link>
        <description>Document23</description>
        <address>url 2</address>
    </link>
    <link>
        <description>Document43</description>
        <address>url 3</address>
    </link>
    <regNum>201801289307</regNum>
    <order>3</order>
    <seqNum>24447778</seqNum>
    <codType>6</codType>
    <descType>Blah</descType>
</document>
```

I have created a dict like this:

```
op = {}
op['doc_dict'] = {"descriDoc":[], "orderDoc":[], "seqNum":[], "codType":[], "descType":[]}
op['doc_dict']['link_dict'] = {"seqNum":[], "linkUrl":[]}
```

I would like to achieve a DICT where I can match each URL inside the **LINK** tags to it's parent **DOCUMENT** using the value inside the **seqNum** tag

```
{'doc_dict': {'descriDoc': ["blah, blah, blah"], 'orderDoc': ["4"], 'seqNum': ["24447779"],
              'codType': ["6"], 'descType': ["Blah1"],
              'link_dict': {'seqNum': ["24447779"], 'linkUrl': ["url 5", "url 7", "url 9"]}}}
```

Any idea on how to get the above DICT would be great. All my approaches failed.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

I have used the List comprehension and solved the question.

```
def edicao(filename): 
    op = []
    tree = ET.parse(filename) #read in the XML

    for item in tree.iter(tag = 'document'):
        doc = {}
        doc["descriDoc"] = item.find('description').text
        doc["orderDoc"] = item.find('order').text
        doc["seqNum"] = item.find('seqNum').text
        doc["links"] = [{'seqNum':item.find('seqNum').text,
                     'descricaoDoc':e.find('description').text,
                     'url':e.find('address').text} for e in item.findall('link')]
        op.append(doc)

   return op
```

Cheers,